# Need to remove Try Ubuntu or Install Ubunut install dialog from customized live Ubuntu USB

Tags: customization

I need to remove the  below Install dialog from my custom live usb. (After boot up the live system using custom Ubuntu bootable USB)

[image]

Comment: remove the maybe ubiquity from grub.cfg and from txt.cfg

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you saying that you would use this as only live disk and would always want to "Try Ubuntu" by default without showing this dialog? see if [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) helps.

Comment: @JijoJoseph yes you are correct. Above GUI dialog shown every reboot. I need to remove it.

Comment: Ok. check if the link provided above does help. Ubuntu's installer is Ubiquity. You would need to configure that in your custom live CD.  I haven't done this so my knowledge is limited. I think you should get some details visiting the link above.

Answer (score 1):

As @C.S Cameron suggested I checked the grub.cfg file. and removed this part `maybe-ubiquity` from the below line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for letting us know it worked for you. +10